# Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path.Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase for authorising my web app using node.js,
and whenever I send the request for a signup, I am getting this:
Error:

> Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/users/test@gmail.com". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

```
 var promise = db.ref(`/users/` + req.body.userid).set({
    password: req.body.password
  });
  promise
    .then((data) => {
      //alert('Record added');
      res.status(200).json({
        status: "Success",
        message: "Welcome" + userid
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
db.ref(`/users/` + req.body.userid)
```

You are trying to use a `.` in the reference and the reference can't contain special characters, as the error says.

Try changing the `req.body.userid` with `email@gmailcom` or change the id to be an alphanumeric one to identify the user.